# How to execute a python file in command with different arguments

Tags: python, batch-file, command

I have a python file which accept four arguments as input. I run the python file in Anaconda environment by this command.

`python "\python.py" --arg1 "account" --arg2 "userid" --arg3 "action" --arg4 "filename"`

May I know any ideas to execute this command for many times with different userid and filename arguments? Any batch file could help to do this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

One way actually involves python - make a script that activates the original script with different arguments each time, with something like that:

```py
import os  # for os.system, which executes the command in a subshell.

list_of_args = [[1,2,3,4],[a,b,c,d],...,]

for item in list_of_args:
    os.system(f'python "\python.py" --arg1 {item[0]} --arg2 {item[1]} --arg3 {item[2]} --arg4 {item[3]}')
```

Another option using the same "storage" method is, but with a different string formatting way is:

```py
for item in list_of_args:
    os.system('python "\python.py" --arg1 {} --arg2 {} --arg3 {} --arg4 {}'.format(*item))
```

There are other options, including user input or importing data from a file(an excel sheet for example), etc, even not using python. This is just a simple example that stays in what you've already delved a bit in :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. May I know how to import the arguments from an excel file as well? I am considering that option as well

Comment: This is a pretty easy guide - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-excel-file-using-python/. You can also use the pandas module(https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) and there are plenty more xlsx/csv reading modules out there. Good luck!

Comment: Also, if my answer satisfies you, please select it as accepted :)